# Missing private key XCode

Tags: ios, xcode, certificate, private-key

I want to upload an app using Xcode to the TestFlight and I've come across some problem stating that my private key was missing. I've recently moved to a Macbook Air from Macbook Pro. The error is:

"{Company Name} has 3 Apple Distribution certificates but their private keys are not installed. Contact the creator of one of these certificates to get a copy of the private key. "

Actually, I am one of the developers listed there. The statement assumes that I know how to give a copy of the private certificate to myself, but I don't. I asked myself twice, like "give it please please" but I ended up with no hope. Then, I tried to inform myself about the situation, so I could help myself.

All the help stuff was like "delete the old certificate and create a new one" but I don't think it's the only workaround, because if it was, the error message would say "missing private key, delete the old one and create new". So I think there's some other way to kind of "transfer" the old private key to the new machine.

I tried getting to the Keychain Access of the old machine. I've looked up private keys that might exists there, but I've come across a huge list. The only thing that I know is some random ID of the certificate (ZH24....) and the expiry date: Sep 2th 2021.

[image]

In the list of private keys, the dates are absent. I know that private keys don't expire, but the real problem is, I can't track which private key I'm dealing with, if only there was a date or some alias which is somewhat informative. Anyway, I tried a random one, right-clicked, and exported. A password screen popped up, I didn't set any password. Then, I ended up with a p12 file. I've airdropped it to the new machine (Macbook Air). Double clicked it, and ended up with this screen:

[image]

Great! By the way, I tried exporting all the private keys that I've seen there and imported them on the new machine, some of them worked, but the problem didn't go.

[image]

The only improvement I've seen is, now the development certificate (not distribution) at Sep 2th is no longer missing its private key.

The question is: Provided that my old machine (Macbook Pro) is currently able to distribute the app. So, is there some way to get it working on the new machine?

Comment: For a larger team you can also look into fastlane match: https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/match/

Answer (score 0):

Try exporting the public and private key together. Go to the `login` keychain (left-hand menu in Keychain Access), then click "My Certificates".

Then click on the certificate you want to export to show the private key. Select both rows, right-click and click "Export".